# In what order should I read the lights novels of 'Tokyo Ghoul'?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I've recently started reading the manga of *Tokyo Ghoul* and there were some terms like Kakugan, Kagune etc. and some characters mentioned which are not told earlier by the manga.

I then found that there are light novels of *Tokyo Ghoul* which can help me understand the backstory of characters more clearly and the terms too.

So, in which order should I read the novels? And should I read the manga before or after reading the light novels?

Comment: The answer to [the same question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10154641245) says that they are not particularly dependent on each other. You can start anywhere.